# Etsy API won't return store's listings

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, etsy

Working on my first API call for a WordPress widget I am confused why the request is returning nothing when I try to target a store.  When I read the documentation I saw [`findAllShops`](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/shop#method_findallshops) and tried:

```
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$apishop = 'FooBar';

$apiurl = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/:' . $apishop . '/listings/active?api_key=' . $apikey;
```

and

```
$apiurl = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/:' . $apishop . '/listings/active?method=GET&api_key=:' . $apikey;
```

but my JSON file returns blank. Referencing the tag [etsy](/questions/tagged/etsy) I was led to [Getting all listing images from an Etsy shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596917/getting-all-listing-images-from-an-etsy-shop) but when I tried to use:

```
$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$apishop = 'FooBar';

$apiurl = 'https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/:' . $apishop . '/listings/active?api_key=' . $apikey;
```

my JSON file returned blank.  After researching Etsy's API documentation it does say that [`getShop`](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/reference/shop#method_getshop) method should get the parameters of `shop_id` with type array in the form of `id` or `name`.  How can I get the API to return JSON for a shop by it's `name` and NOT by the `id`?

### Edit:

After comments, I was under the impression I am able to pull shop name from:

[image]

and when I visit `array(shop_id_or_name)` I get:

> Either a shop's numeric ID or login name. (Note: shop IDs are not
>   interchangeable with user IDs.)

I could be misunderstanding it but based on that I thought I was able to get the shop's name.

I also tried these on [Apigee's etsy console](https://apigee.com/console/etsy) and when I select the method `findAllShops` I get the request URL:

```
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/private/shops
```

and I took this and added my token.  Still returns a blank JSON file.

Comment: Are you getting return headers?  Rate limit in effect?

Comment: You can't get getShop to use the name, since the API doesn't seem to be built that way. You can try to use the function above it, getAllShops, to find the shop_id.

Comment: @aynber says I should be able to get shop name [here](https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/api_basics#type_shop_id_or_name), no??

Comment: @Darth_Vader I missed that part, so I sit corrected.

Comment: @Kkinsey I pulled every procedure from [apigee's console](https://apigee.com/console/etsy) and just added my token in my PHP file.

Comment: If you try it barebones `https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/` does it return anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your request string is all correct, except the colon (`:`) before the `shop_id`.

For example:

**Returns all shops**

`https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/?api_key=$apikey`

**Return a specific shop by ID or name**

`https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/$shop_id_or_name?api_key=$apikey`

**Return all active listings from a specific shop**

`https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/$shop_id_or_name/listings/active?api_key=$apikey`

All tested on [Apigee's etsy console](https://apigee.com/console/etsy)